# What are the alternatives for Xposed framework on Pie? Preferably without triggering Safety Net?

Tags: 9.0-pie, xposed-framework, safety-net, edxposed

Xposed development has been in a limbo with the last update being a [beta released a year ago](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811).

Die hard fans of Xposed  hesitate to upgrade Android, in the absence of Xposed support.This is true for the latest Android Pie as well. Magisk is useful but cannot replace Xposed for deep stuff. Yet another concern is Safety Net getting triggered when Xposed framework is installed through Magisk.

What are the alternatives available? Preferably without triggering Safety Net?

*Note* :

1. This is a self answered question to share my recent foray into this after upgrading to Pie.
2. Moderators are welcome to make this a wiki Q and A if it attracts more updates or if deemed fit.

Comment: **There have been changes in Magisk /EdXposed drivers which are explained in this answer. Please see that https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/131553**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*There are significant changes in Magisk /EdXposed drivers which are updated here* [How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/131553)

*Please refer to updated installation instructions*.

---

*Alternatives to Xposed (rovo89) are:

- [Virtual Xposed](https://virtualxposed.com/) - a rootless Xposed and therefore far less capable. I didn't investigate further for this reason but I read that development on this has stopped (unconfirmed).
- [Tai-Chi Xposed](https://virtualxposed.com/tai-chi/) by the same developer of Virtual Xposed and [supports Android Pie](https://github.com/tiann/Tai-Chi). Said to be close sourced and likely to be paid module per some reports.
- [Edxposed](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed). This is the alternative I chose.

*Disclaimer*: I am not a developer nor am I affiliated to any app or module.

## Is it safe?

**Yes**

For an average user like me, two factors help decide:

- **Open Source Vs Close Source** Edxposed is  Open source. I have no understanding of code and cannot draw any conclusion from looking at code. But yes, being open source means it is subject to scrutiny by knowledgeable folks and therefore safer (Please don't drag me into open source discussion, rather post an alternative answer :).
- **Provenance or trust attached**

  - The last  Xposed update by rovo89 is also close sourced (as against earlier versions which are open source). This being close source would not have detracted people from using it purely based on developer's reputation.
  - In the case of Edxposed, my trust lies with Marcel (aka M66B) who has developed several privacy centered modules / apps such as [NetGuard](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-netguard-root-firewall-t3233012), [Xprivacy](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacy-ultimate-android-privacy-app-t2320783), [XprivacyLua](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacylua6-0-android-privacy-manager-t3730663) and [FairEmail](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/source-email-t3824168). For me, when a staunch privacy advocate like Marcel [starts development using EdXposed](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78862830&postcount=3892)(edit-completed development), that's pretty much sovereign guarantee despite [some warnings about close source](https://www.xda-developers.com/xposed-framework-unofficial-port-android-pie/) (Incidentally, this claim is incorrect and a Reddit user informed XDA portal. To clarify again, it is open source)

## Is it as good as Xposed and can I use all Xposed modules?

- It is not (yet) as powerful as Xposed because it lacks support at this stage for *resource hooks* but it may get added hopefully.
- It is still in beta stage but a lot of modules work already. See [[Updated] List of Xposed modules for Android Pie working with Ed Xposed Framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/list-xposed-modules-android-pie-ed-t3892768/page3) for a list of working and non-working modules which is being updated. Take this list with a pinch of salt - it may mean anything from doesn't crash and works partially to fully works. See last question below.
- For me XPrivacy Lua works and works far better on EdXposed than on the beta version of Xposed on Oreo. Another must module for me is [Maxlock](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.maxr1998.xposed.maxlock) which works fine. Only one I want is GravityBox and C3C076 , developer of GravityBox is [considering development for EdXposed](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78850710&postcount=1207) and it is likely others follow suit.

## Does it pass Safety Net?

**Yes** :)

## OK, how do I install it?

**Check for updates from corresponding links below as they would change being a beta. Valid as on 12 Feb 19 and will not be updated in this answer**. See [How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/131553) for a more recent method

**Source** [Android 9.0 uses xposed solutions](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/android-9-0-xposed-solutions-t3889513) as updated

Use Magisk order to install these modules in the *same order* ( You won't find them in the magisk repo. Download them and from Magisk Downloads option click on the **+** to install and they will appear as Magisk Modules)

1. [Magisk-riru-core-arm-arm64-v10.zip](https://github.com/RikkaApps/Riru/releases)
2. [Magisk-EdXposed-arm-arm64-v x.x_beta-release.zip](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed/releases)
3. Don't reboot yet , install <s>[XposedInstaller_by_dvdandroid_19_10_18. apk](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=11410963190603845164) or [from XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/dl/?id=30660)</s>

[magisk-EdXposed-v0.2.9.8_beta1-release.zip](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed/releases) (check for updates in subsequent releases)

4. Reboot.

## Does it work on modded UI's like that of Samsung , MiUI, Poco etc?

Traditionally XPosed always had a problem with such devices but EdXposed seems to fare better. Issues with some devices are reported so YMMV (check out the linked XDA thread)

## List of  modules that are  fully optimized?

Developers would need to upgrade their modules for working with Pie AND EdXposed. As of now, the following modules meet these requirements

- XPrivacy Lua
- Xposed Edge Pro
- [Gravity Box Beta](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v9-0-0-beta-1-android-9-t3908768) released on 08 Mar 19.

**Notes**

- You may need multiple reboots.
- Ignore the warning on the installer *Xposed not yet compatible ...with SDK 28...or your Android architecture (see pic below)*.
- You may find at times that installer is disabled - reinstall and reboot to fix. For some , *soft reboot* from installer fixes the problem (root permission needs to be given for installer).
- Whenever Installer is upgraded, it is better in my experience to uninstall the earlier installer and install the newer one to prevent instability
- Your device may be noticeably slower to respond - that's a price to pay till things stabilize.
- Some modules may work with earlier versions of Edxposed and not with later versions or vice-versa.
- **Pro-tip** Just in case you land up installing a module that ends up in a boot loop or creates some other problem , it is handy to have [[Tool][2018.8.1] Magisk Manager for Recovery Mode (mm)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-tool-magisk-manager-recovery-mode-t3693165) installed so that you can disable or uninstall the Xposed modules from Magisk.

Screenshots are from my MiA1 (Android one) running stock OS with latest Magisk 18.1

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

Happy Xposing !

Comment: Taichi is on GitHub here: https://github.com/taichi-framework/TaiChi

Comment: TaiChi is on GitHub, but its source code is not. The developer [does not want to open source it](https://github.com/taichi-framework/TaiChi/issues/998).

Answer (score 2):

Relatively new entries on the scene are [SPatch (Beta)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/beta-spatch-a-new-root-free-xposed-framework.4192279/) (tried) and perhaps a lesser popular [Xpatch](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-xpatch-using-xposed-modules-to-modify-apps-without-root-device.3922602/).

**What is SPatch ?**

> Let devices without root or bootloader unlock to use Xposed framework!
> SPatch is a new root free Xposed framework, also available for devices
> not unlock bootloader. Support both ARM(SandHook) and X86(SHook, for
> Android emulator)

System requirements:
Android 6.0+ (Support Android 11)
256MB ram or more
128MB free disk space

**Usage**

Spatch has some kind of Virtual xposed look and feel and overall functionality is almost similar though the former has extra tweaks for pro users plus users can install SPromoter (a helper app) for module management

> 1. Open SPatch app and wait until password activity appear
> 2. Input zero four times, then long press D button
> 3. Click visit button, remember numbers that pop up from the top of window, then input the numbers you remember
> 4. Click M button for Xposed or Cydia modules injecting, V for virtual machine, T for hack tools, rest of all for your explore
> 5. Click add button for add application you installed or apk file in internal storage, wait for action finish then reinstall or install
>    application. Application you add by SPatch will load all Xposed
>    modules you installed. You can use SPromoter for module managing.

[image]

**What is Xpatch**

> Xpatch is a jar tool which is used to repackage the apk file. Then,
> the new apk can load any Xposed modules installed in the android
> system.
>
> This is a way to use Xposed modules without root your device.
>
> It is easy way to modify one app using xposed module. And any apps
> changed by Xpatch can load every modules downloaded in the Xposed
> Module Repository.

Haven't used Xpatch but from the developer page, the usage instructions are provided:

**How to use**

> 1. Download the latest jar file from the my [github release page](https://github.com/WindySha/Xpatch).
> 2. Run this command in the Windows/Mac console:
>
>    `$ java -jar ../../xpatch.jar ../../source.apk`

Basically the main idea here is that a new apk is produced in the same folder as source apk.

This apk can **load any xposed modules installed** in the device.(Support up to Android 11)

Learn more [here](https://github.com/WindySha/Xpatch/blob/6ec0f3c16128dda46ab05bdd915d66ebbdaaf9fc/README_en.md)

Xpatch source code: https://github.com/WindySha/Xpatch

Comment: sure thanks! will try LSPosed, right now on nougat but planning to upgrade to pie soon.

Comment: Just an update, managed to install LSPosed, and its very ideal, loving it ;)