# How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net

Tags: xposed-framework, magisk, safety-net, oneplus-7, edxposed

Further to this question [What are the alternatives for Xposed framework on Pie? Preferably without triggering Safety Net?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207633/131553)

**How does one install EdXposed on Android 10?**

**Notes:**

1. This is a self answered question consolidating information from several threads on XDA / Github and my experience on Oneplus 7 to give a helpful start to that dying breed who like to install [xposed-framework](/questions/tagged/xposed-framework) modules . Edxposed is still in beta and Android 10 is recently released, so there would be many changes to this answer in future. Since I do not intend to update this answer with developments, others are welcome to add and modify. Moderators are welcome to make this a community wiki if warranted.
2. Answer is generic in nature and for issues relating to installation / modules you are better off asking in respective device/module threads in XDA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[xposed-framework](/questions/tagged/xposed-framework) is de facto dead , the last update being more than two years ago and that too for Oreo and there is no news of further updates.

EdXposed , being open source is a preferred alternative for me and hence this answer. EdXposed [*officially supports Android 10*](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed/releases) (Incidentally,some Xposed modules were working in earlier versions of EdXposed too) .

**Pre-requisites** (need to be updated from sources or as prompted by EdXPosed manager).

- Magisk v20 + , with Magisk Manager from [official Magisk thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445).
- Riru-core latest release from Magisk modules or from [GitHub](https://github.com/RikkaApps/Riru/releases). (See , this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231178/131553) too. Simply put, latest may not be what you want always)
- EdXposed drivers YAHFA/Sandhook from [Github](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed/releases)
- [EdXposed manager](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposedManager/releases). Note that [EdXposed installer](https://github.com/solohsu/XposedInstaller/releases) /  original Xposed Installer are  *not* supported / recommended (respectively).

**Installation**

- Obviously you have a rooted device running Android 10, with Magisk installed.
- Install Riru-core module first.
- YAHFA or Sandhook drivers. YAHFA is relatively slower but stable by most accounts compared to Sandhook. You would need to check XDA for what works best for your device/Android version. For me, it has been YAHFA on my earlier and current device. These can be installed directly if using Magisk 20.2 plus

**Note:** Prior to 29 February 20,YAHFA /Sandhook modules available on Magisk repo  required patched drivers / custom Magisk. This was a little tedious and the process is at the end of the answer, retained for history and not applicable anymore (hence strike through text)

- Reboot, install EdXPosed manager , add Android 10 ready modules and profit!

**Does it pass Safety Net?**:  <s>**Yes**</s>

**Edit:** Not anymore. Please see [Magisk will fail Safety-Net hereafter. Why?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221976/131553)

**Notes**

- Xposed module development isn't what it used to be so there are only a few Android 10 ready Xposed modules. The ones I care for and  Android 10 ready are:

  ```
  * [XPrivacy Lua](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacylua6-0-android-privacy-manager-t3730663). This works beautifully with the same module that worked on earlier Android versions.
  ```

  - [Gravity Box for 10 (beta)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v10-0-0-beta-1-android-10-t3974497). With EdXposed Whitelist functionality turned off in EdXposed Manager

    - [3C All in one toolbox](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-2-3-3c-toolbox-pro-t2942186).
    - [Xposed Edge Pro](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-edgepro-v2-0-release-t3525566).
- Ill advised as it may be, one may be tempted to try other modules too. If they work, please update here. But if they don't work and create freezes, reboots , system lags (pretty common symptoms), you need to disable those modules without a nuclear [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset). To do that you have two methods available:

  1. [Magisk Manager for Recovery Mode (mm)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-tool-magisk-manager-recovery-mode-t3693165). This module can be installed directly from Magisk but *it will not work* because it hasn't been updated to support Magisk versions beyond 19. You need to boot into TWRP (if TWRP is not permanently installed) and sideload the module. Next,from the recovery terminal run  `mm or sh /sdcard/mm` and disable all modules or the offending module and reboot.

2. Grant shell privileges to Magisk (this would have security implications, I guess) . [Source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=80389563&postcount=23)

> The best way is to grant shell su privileges with magisk in advanced by doing `adb shell` then `su` . Magisk will then ask to grant root to shell and you can use it even while bootlooping.
> If you were to bootloop you'd then run `adb shell` then `touch /data/adb/modules/riru_edxposed_sandhook/disable` (or YAHFA )

3. There is a [tool on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/tool-magisk-manager-recovery-tool-v1-0-t3866502) that may help (not tried by me).
4. From [Ronan's comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218179/how-to-install-edxposed-on-android-10-without-triggering-safety-net#comment282583_218180) (thanks)

> Don't forget that if a module does boot loop you, you can delete the EdXposed module via TWRP. Just go to the file manager and head to `data/adb/.magisk/modules`

- Other tips as mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207634/131553) may be useful.

Happy Xposing !

Screenshots from OnePlus7 running stock Android 10 (Click to enlarge)

[[image: IMG:]][1]
[[image: IMG:]][2]
[[image: IMG:]][3]
[[image: IMG:]][4]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNmZ4.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOMNC.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUTtM.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/seTc8.jpg

---

---

Text below is redundant but retained for context

<s>Now, comes the tricky part. As you can see [in the official support for 10 release](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed/releases), these drivers **cannot** be directly installed through Magisk (by going to Magisk downloads, pressing **+** and flashing the zip). These require some *sepolicy* changes to be done:</s>

1. Through Magisk once the request (PR) is accepted by Magisk developer , in which case the drivers hosted on Magisk modules should work. This was hoped with the latest release of Magisk today , but it didn't happen. Update 15/12/19 [likely to be officially supported soon](https://mobile.twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1203808733953966080)

or

2. *Custom Magisk build* links are [hosted here](https://github.com/solohsu/magisk_files). From Magisk settings , the update channel needs to be changed to "custom" and the link at custom update channel pasted there. This would prompt an update request and once you accept it, you have the custom build installed. I was wary of going this route fearing possible complications and also because PR as mentioned above was not accepted by Magisk developer.

or

3. Using drivers that have the *sepolicy* changes incorporated in the drivers themselves , instead of Magisk side. At the moment, you can find  [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=80660829&postcount=92) . This hopefully would be a temporary arrangement and the first option of changes being incorporated in Magisk itself materializes soon (you can add your voice for support in [the PR](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/pull/1685) 
   :)

---

Comment: In case you are wondering, Magisk Manager looks different because I "hid" it to hide root from some apps. As a side note you can even name the manager with emoticons instead of text!

Comment: Cat and mouse game continues... If safety net is tripped this [fix](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed/issues/386#) may help ( worked for me). It's always advisable to keep track of Github issues

Comment: As mentioned in the official [telegram channel](https://t.me/EdXposed/72) the new safetynet mechanism *should* (might?) only be enabled on devices with "non-software [attestation level](https://source.android.com/security/keystore/attestation#securitylevel-values)". It's not ***all*** lost.

Comment: @mirh- your source says *may*, so it's not certain. This was also discussed in the tweets of John Wu but the conclusion was that is a temporary breather. Thanks for drawing attention

Comment: It is not certain in the sense that the author could not test this himself imo. But I struggle to see how else the situation could work out if you don't have the required hardware-backed credentials at all. Either they pull the plug on every phone older than ~2017 (stock or not), or these should keep working as they have always done. Then yes, they are indeed still [experimenting](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1238514375150850048) and support for even all other phones is still "swinging", but that wasn't my point.

Comment: @mirh Yes, I agree there's confusion. One cm only hope it works in our favor. Thanks for your interest and look forward to your inputs

Comment: what is latest Riru version compatible with EdXposed installer? can I update Riru after EdXposed was installed or will it break?

Comment: @alecxs sorry don't know , I am using LSPosed which I mentioned in my similar answer on Android 12 installation// It's far more better IMO// Yes, you can and should update Riru, it won't break

Comment: I think I will stay at EdXposed for reason https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/edxposed-vs-lsposed.4297433/post-86057527

Comment: @alecxs that is fine if you have incompatible modules //device is smoother with Lsposed, though more efforts are needed.  Ultimately, it's what you are comfortable with //But with Riru officially deprecated... How long can one carry on with Riru?

Comment: Magisk is dead anyway as topjohnwu sold his soul to the devil