# Disable Chromecast audio interrruption/autopauze when using camera, microphone or receiving phonecall

Tags: audio, streaming, chromecast

I know some people like the **auto-pauze** function when receiving a phone call so so they are not interrupted by their own music playing. But I am personally very annoyed by that function. When I'm listening to the radio (streaming trough Chromecast audio) I do not want my live stream to be interrupted because I make a photo or video, ask something to my phone or receive a phone call. When I'm listening to a podcast it doesn't even resume after using the camera, the podcast just restarts from the beginning. Very annoying.

After some trial and error I discovered it is the app who plays the audio that interrupts it on an event, not Android itself. Yes it's a bad app that does not offer options to disable that function but its the only one available as it is from the national government. So my question to the community **is** if **there** is **a way to block** the ***events*** (camera, microphone, phone call) **from being noticed by the app** streaming to my Chromecast.

ps: the app(s) I'm referring to are the ones from VRT/RTBF (Belgian national radio).

Comment: Possible if your device is rooted

Comment: good news, my device is rooted, with magisk. soo tell me how?

Comment: You need to install EdXposed (see https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/131553) and then Xprivacy Lua module and deny that app those permissions. If you have issues ask in the Xda thread of module. But note that it will work only if the app is using Java and not some obfuscated code