# Disable xposed from TWRP

Tags: adb, twrp, xposed-framework

An xposed module screwed my interface. It's all black.

I can't access /data/data from within TWRP due to some stupid encription problem.

Is there another way to disable xposed ?

Losing data is out of the question.

Can't access data through ADB either: debugging is disabled

---

**Update:**

**Too late.**

Did something on TWRP and lost everything. Even the ROM got corrupted. Had to reflash EVERYTHING

Chaos was going on: the screen was not only black, but completely irresponsible. The only dialog available was the Turn Off/Reboot. Safe mode useless.
TWRP showed Internal and External storages as 0MB. Couldn't mount either. Not even system could be mounted. Written... even less.

Maybe all this had something to do with encryption. I could never disable encryption on this phone (apparently it is impossible)

If it still has some use:

XT1925-5 (Moto G6)

TWRP 3.3.1.0

Boot, Xposed and Magisc were all flashed by either fastboot or TWRP

I can't remember the exposed version. The module was something like P-fy (change appearance of Oreo to look like Pie. Stay away from this crap)

---

**Update 2:**

There seems to be a way to disable xposed by machine gunning any hardware button after logo during boot. Can't test now.
I was trying to cripple xposed by modding something at data/data/. Hard way it seems.

---

**Finally:** For the reasons above, I can't evaluate the answers of those who attempted to help. Hope it helps the next guy. By me, the thread can be deleted.

Comment: How did you root your device? Is root systemless? `dm-verity` status? If enabled are you willing to disable (OTA updates won't work)? SELinux status? How did you flash Xposed? In `/system` partition or systemless? Through Magisk? Which Xposed version and module exactly? Which device and Android version? Is it system-as-root or A/B device? Encryption is FDE or FBE? None of the available custom recoveries for your device can decrypt `/data`? Only screwed interface is inaccessible or any other problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is an Xposed disabler zip file that can be found on this [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053/post24267797#post24267797) from Xda-developers. In case you installed the systemless Xposed, I am not sure if it will be disable. You need to install the zip from TWRP as you would for other zip files.

Comment: That will not work for systemless

Answer (score 0):

If it is systemless root (most likely) , a couple of methods mentioned in the last part of my answer [How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/13). It's a repetition but it may help those seeking a specific answer for this :

1. [Magisk Manager for Recovery Mode (mm)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-tool-magisk-manager-recovery-mode-t3693165). This module can be installed directly from Magisk but *it will not work* because it hasn't been updated to support Magisk versions beyond 19. You need to boot into TWRP (if TWRP is not permanently installed) and sideload the module. Next,from the recovery terminal run `mm or sh /sdcard/mm` and disable all modules or the offending module and reboot.
   (Tip: double click for *enter*)
2. Grant shell privileges to Magisk (this would have security implications, I guess) . [Source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=80389563&postcount=23)

> The best way is to grant shell su privileges with magisk in advanced by doing `adb shell` then `su` . Magisk will then ask to grant root to shell and you can use it even while bootlooping.
>   If you were to bootloop you'd then run `adb shell` then `touch /data/adb/modules/riru_edxposed_sandhook/disable` (or YAHFA ).