# How to get vertical recent/overview navigation in Android 10?

Tags: magisk, recents-screen, android-10, oxygenos, oneplus-6

I updated my OnePlus 6 to Android 10 (OxygenOS 10.3.2) recently and having a hard time to use it because of the horizontal overview navigation introduced from Android 9.

I am in want of replacing horizontal overview/recent apps navigation with vertical one (as was available till Android 8).

In Android 9, the trick for my stock ROM was to replace OnePlus launcher with an older version from Android 8 build. However, this trick doesn't work on Android 10 anymore. Neither does disabling or removing the stock OnePlus launcher. It just disables Overview functionality at my face than.

I primarily use Nova launcher. I have tried to use one or two other launchers from Play Store in the hope that they might  bring vertical overview on the table, but all at vain.

So, how do I bring back vertical overview in Android 10 in OnePlus 6?

Note 1: I am only looking for answers as solutions that does the job I am asking for. Nothing else.

Note 2: the device is rooted with Magisk.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138427/discussion-on-question-by-firelord-how-to-get-vertical-recent-overview-navigatio).

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround and *not* what the OP wants in terms of vertical recents ( I don't think it's possible for reasons mentioned at the end of answer).

- Install EdXposed ([How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/131553)), [Xposed Edge Pro](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-edgepro-v2-0-release-t3525566) at a minimum and [Gravity Box for 10 (beta)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v10-0-0-beta-1-android-10-t3974497) (preferred).
- In Xposed Edge Pro, enable gestures and select any edge (if you choose edge covered by keyboard, make sure in app preferences, to enable) where you want the gestures to be triggered (right bottom in the screenshot) and associate *running apps drawer* action with the gesture.

[image]
[image]

(Click to enlarge)

- When you activate the gesture, it shows running apps which is far more easier way of accessing recent apps instead of multiple horizontal swipes.

[image]

(Click to enlarge)

- You are done but you need to remember to activate the gesture *but* muscle memory tells you to tap the recent icon. If you want to associate running apps drawer with tapping the recents icon, you needn't select the gesture as described above. In Gravitybox Navigation keys action → Single tap action  → Custom action  → Shortcuts  → Xposed Edge Pro actions  → running apps drawer
- Lastly, my guess as to why what OP wants cannot happen unless the OnePlus launcher is modified, somehow. You can see the launcher in the screenshot above (second row, second icon) but you don't see that using Nova recents. It's reasonable to assume that a third party launcher works with the support of OnePlus launcher and unless the base is modified, you won't get vertical apps. The trick (of installing old version of OnePlus launcher) didn't work probably because of compatibility with Android 10. If you try to freeze or uninstall OnePlus launcher, the recents key doesn't work. This further supports my theory but I haven't investigated further.

Comment: Nice work-around! So the other Edge features (like Pie) do not conflict with similar ones of Gravitybox? If I were to try your solution, that might be ignoring two conflicts (GB already says not to use with LOS) #D // Btw: Do you know a "real solution" not bound to OnePlus or Samsung devices (and not involving Google/Play stuff)? I'm in the same boat with a Fairphone 2 on Android 10.

Comment: PS: to associate that "running apps drawer" with the recents key, you probably do not even need GB. Couldn't that be assigned right from within EE: *Keys › Recent Apps › Click"? // PS: A pity that module is not FOSS. They only have the translations on Github, not the actual app code :(

Comment: @Izzy Thanks. Not aware of a *real* workaround since it is an Android 10 feature - one of those bad features added//Xposed Edge does not clash with GB//Xposed Edge dev seems to Jane got fed up with Android changes and isn't supporting new versions //on Play Store he tells **not** to buy his pro app :(

Comment: Comments crossed. I don't recall what happened or if I didn't try your second suggestion on Android 10/!On 11 EE is broke for most part

Comment: Similar work-around not requiring root/Magisk/Xposed: [Taskbar](https://github.com/farmerbb/Taskbar) ([F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.farmerbb.taskbar/) / [Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farmerbb.taskbar)). Also includes "Start Menu" for all installed apps. Or [Gardine](https://f-droid.org/packages/by.yauhenl.gardine/). [Some more](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_taskswitcher) if you're happy with Play Store & Trackers.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has a tool to modify the UI called Good Lock in both galaxy store and play store. Within that there is an tool called "Task Changer" that let me change the recent app list to a verticle style as before in earlier Android versions. I'm also using Nova.