# Good app-switching on Android 10

Tags: android-10, multitasking

I have a Xiaomi Mi Pad 4 tablet, on a custom ROM (Floko), including Magisk and root.

Today decided to update to Android 10.

I can't find a way to make multitasking feel good again.

The new app switchers put only 1 app per screen and give mile-long scroll distances to the others.

The old Oreo fallback has been removed from AOSP. [[1]](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78554685&postcount=2)
(It stacked apps vertically, with their titles - you had access to 4/5 apps on the same screen.)

My rom has the option to use OmniSwitch recents, which put more apps on the same screen, but they disable the double-tap to previous app functionality. Also not the best recebts UI (though way ahead of the newer ones).

Semi-related: The pixel launcher puts some icons down in the recents based on I don't know what logic, but even those get obliterated when I switch launchers. And I want to switch launchers badly, because the pixel launcher doesn't let me manage home screens.

Any way to make app switching good again (rom or app)? I'd rather not downgrade, cuz the Pie rom had some other issues with my device (Which might end up worth it, given how frequently I end up app-switching and what a horrible experience it is now.)

Comment: Try this solution https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222088/131553

Comment: Interesting. Help site says asking software rec questions are expressly off-topic for this site. In the mean time I've been cavorting around the play store, and I did find something which accomplish the same thing as the answer you linked with way less hassle - an app called "Taskbar". I also tried a million launchers, some of which came with their own recents providers(switchable via a magisk module called "Quick Switch"). Sadly all of them reported incompatible. So the original question still stands. At least until I downgrade to Pie, which is the direction we're heading for right now.