# How can I condense the icons in the quick settings panel on Android?

Tags: notification-icons, android-10, quick-settings

Icons in the  quick settings panel look like:

[image]

But instead I would like to make the icons smaller:

[image]

How can I condense the icons in the  quick settings panel on Android?

Interestingly the two above screenshots were on the same unrooted phone, but it was the first time I saw the small icons, and it reverted back to the normal sized icons the next day. No idea what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot show the "quick settings panel" with "tiles" for actions.

The number of "tiles" per row is defined by ROM and you can't change that (unless your ROM provides a setting for doing that). If your device is rooted, there could be solutions. This is defined by a system UI property `quick_settings_min_num_tiles` (not sure if it is ROM dependent)

Gravity Box EdXposed module is one way to do this on rooted devices (See this
 [How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/131553))