# Add am/pm after the 12-hour clock time in the status bar

Tags: samsung, clock, samsung-galaxy-s-9

The status bar at the top of my Samsung S9+ does not show the am/pm after the time.  The picture below was taken at 3:23 pm local time but you would not know that unless I told you.  It could be 3:23 am.  If I were using a 24-hour clock, I would expect that there not be an am/pm.  However, my time setting is for 12-hour clock and could have an am/pm.  How do I add the am/pm after the time?

[image: Status bar without the am/pm]

Some may say that I can easily tell whether it is am or pm... just look outside.  That may be true at 3:23 am or pm.  However, at 8 pm during the summer time, the sunlight is about the same whether it is morning or evening.  I would have to walk outside to find the sun and then know.  During the winter time, 6 am and pm is completely dark.  There is no sun to help me know.

Let's say I am very tired during the winter and start a nap at 4 pm.  I wake up at 6.  I do not know if I slept for 2 hours or 14 hours.  Most likely I slept for 2 hours but it depends on how much sleep debt I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the [other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225463/96277) that the objective is impossible on devices running a stock ROM, and that it cannot be achieved without root access.

For Samsung devices, [Good Lock](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.goodlock) (available in Galaxy Store), an app from Samsung made [available only in few countries](https://news.samsung.com/global/good-lock-customize-the-way-you-use-your-galaxy-smartphone), can do what you want. It runs on stock Galaxy devices  and does not need root access. Here's what to do. Download Good Lock from the linked app store. Run *Quickstar* from the menu.

It is reasonably easy to follow it. If you are unable to follow it, then search Youtube for *Good Lock*. It should help out.

My experience with Sony devices I have ever had concludes that Sony devices don't support the feature you are after. I can't speak for other brands.

Comment: Hello Roberts. My fellows mod's well meant edit to your answer perhaps caused some issue to you. I can assure you that it was made in good faith, and so is mine. We are a community of Android users who help each other out not just by asking and answering, but by also editing posts to make them more clear, concise, and to the point. This distinguishes us from the forums out there in terms of quality and approach. Please don't feel bad about edits. We actually have a [policy](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/editing) encouraging everyone to make edits. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible **only** if your device is rooted and cannot be achieved on stock devices. Changes to status bar components like the clock, date, battery icon, percentage, etc. require root or a custom ROM

On rooted devices, one way is to install Exposed/EdXposed framework and Gravitybox module (For Android 10, see [How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218179/131553))

Note that Gravitybox does not play well with heavily modified UI, so it's better to check in device/Gravitybox threads on XDA