# Update to Magisk 24.1. Support for XPosed modules / Changes

Tags: magisk, google-pixel-4a, safety-net, root-cloak, lsposed

I am on Pixel 4a running stock Android 12. I was on Magisk 23.x  with Lsposed (as Riru  is anyway [deprecated](https://github.com/RikkaApps/Riru)). I had no need of updating to the latest 24.1, since everything was fine and I didn't keep up with latest Magisk changes.

Till a banking app update ruined my peace, because it detected root (SBI Yono for Indian readers). All my efforts to circumvent root detection failed <sup>@</sup> and I was forced to consider updating Magisk hoping that the *Deny list* feature would help in preventing root detection (though it's not same as Magisk Hide) or else use a  compatible root hiding app Shamiko (stable version released a few days ago).

This looked to be challenging  since **Magisk 24.1 does not support Riru**. So **how do I run Xposed modules like XPrivacyLua, Xposed Edge etc?** This was my biggest worry.

Google-fu didn't help, but a vague comment on Reddit gave hope. More search revealed other issues and their solutions, which are in the answer below. It was worth the effort since Zygisk is a key feature of Magisk and  I may as well step up my game (and your's).

All the best and yes, I won't be updating this to keep up with changes but you hopefully have enough pointers to find your way

<sup>@</sup>Safety-net passed; developer options state hidden;device shows certified in Play Store. Hiding Magisk app 23.x involves jumping through a lot of hoops, so didn't try that.

Comment: "Magisk 24.1 does not support Riru" – sure? I've updated my Fairphone 2 to Magisk 24.1 recently. Riru continues running fine, Edxposed has no issues, Gravitybox (Xposed module) works as it always did. And if you miss the module manager, [see here](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.fox2code.mmm). Screenshot from the latter, on said device: https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/repo/com.fox2code.mmm/en-US/phoneScreenshots/01.jpg (this is Android 11, you're on 12 where it migght look different)

Comment: @izzy with Lsposed it does not support unless you use Lsposed Zygisk version as in answer//I have linked Github for fox module manager and will include your link as well. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**tl:dr;**

- Zygisk = Zygote + Magisk
- Use Zygisk-ified Lsposed (this was the undocumented learning to get Xposed modules running)
- Use Zygisk-ified USNF for safety-net check

---

Previous setup :Magisk 23.x (stable channel),with Lsposed and some Xposed modules.
Update to Magisk 24.1 (app & Magisk) the usual way (through the app)

**Magisk settings**

1. Enable *Zygisk (beta)*
2. *Configure deny list* and select the apps for which you do not Magisk to be loaded (I read that some elements of Magisk Hide are present in this option, but that's too technical for me).
   Make sure all components of selected app are enabled. In screenshot below Citibank *isn't* fully enabled and hence will be detected , whereas Gpay is correctly enabled. The blue bar above the app needs to be fully extended

[image]

- I chose Gpay and couple of banking apps (including SBI), trusted apps with license issues
- From 3 dots menu select system apps and tick Google Play services `com.google.android.gms` (some blogs recommend also packages ending with `gms.unstable`,but I couldn't see that on my device). Note that if you are using USNF module (see below), `com.google.android.gms` will be automatically *unselected*. See [this XDA post for reasons](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/discussion-magisk-the-age-of-zygisk.4393877/page-44#post-86474127)

3. Enable *enforce deny list*

In Magisk modules list previously installed Riru Lsposed and Riru will be disabled and a warning in *red* that says *module suspended because Zygisk is enabled*. Since they are anyway  disabled, I didn't uninstall them, also it gives me flexibility in case I choose to disable Zygisk.

4. Install through Magisk LSPosed **zygisk-release.zip** ([Github](https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPosed/releases)) or from the [Telegram Channel](https://web.telegram.org/z/#-1499638348). Check that previously installed Xposed modules are listed and working fine.

You are good to run Xposed Modules again!

I found this very useful thread on XDA [Magisk - The Age of Zygisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/discussion-magisk-the-age-of-zygisk.4393877/), which has other resources (some listed below) and some issues/solutions faced while upgrading to Magisk 24.1. I had no issues whatsoever.

5. For Safety-net evasion, install Kdragon's Universal Safety Net Fix (USNF),again the **Zygisk** version  from [Github](https://github.com/kdrag0n/safetynet-fix/releases).Magisk 24.1 doesn't have safety-net check built-in, so install Yet Another SafetyNet Attestation Checker (YASNAC) from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rikka.safetynetchecker)/[Github](https://github.com/RikkaW/YASNAC/releases).USNF Magisk module is the only working safety-net fix/root detection solution ATM.

**Edit:** USNF is outdated. Use [Displax SafetyNet-fix](https://github.com/Displax/safetynet-fix/releases) module instead ([xda thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/posts/88726501/) by developer)

6. Since there isn't a built-in Magisk repo anymore, install Fox's Magisk Module Manager from [Github](https://github.com/Fox2Code/FoxMagiskModuleManager/releases) or from [Izzy's repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.fox2code.mmm).
   It lists modules both from the previous Magisk repo, a new repo plus [Androidacy Magisk Modules Repository](https://www.androidacy.com/modules-repo/)
7. Root hiding: install Shamiko from [Github](https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPosed.github.io/releases) or from LSposed telegram channel linked above. AFAIK, it is the only solution to hide Riru itself. The stable version was released a few days ago.Do read the instructions in the zip file. I didn't need to install it but note that denylist (step 3) should be turned off. Though this is from LSPosed stable, it has drawn some [adverse comments](https://twitter.com/realMlgmXyysd/status/1478215324981989380?s=20&t=uZevZVQr-Vxu_B30z-aUsg) from one of the Edxposed team members and it's not open source too. For additional root-hiding methods , see resources at the end of the answer.

Finally, I am on Magisk 24.1 with safety-net check passed, that banking app working and importantly Xposed modules running fine. All the best!

**Additional resources**

- Here's an XDA thread on [Google Pay/Wallet](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/discussion-google-pay-magisk-discussion-thread.3906703/) post rooting related (hiding).
- [Hide My Applist - A Brief Guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/hide-my-applist-a-brief-guide.4519731/)

Comment: Why is USNF outdated? For some idea see chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts)