# How to change my install directory on Android 10?

Tags: root-access, sd-card, installation, android-10

I have an Alcatel phone that has Android 10 on it. I want to change the installation directory from phone memory to SD memory but it doesn't have such an option in it's settings. So I want to know should I root the phone to get such an access or there is another way doing that?

Also like to know if it is safe doing that using Magisk or there is something better? Because I also do have my bank application, Amazon, etc. installed on my phone!

Comment: [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)

Comment: @alecxs: As I said in my question, my phone doesn't have this option on it's default settings. I want to know if any other apps/ways I can do it?

Comment: @alecxs: In many tutorials they say go to settings, storage settings, then format the SD card as internal storage, but my alcatel 5004R device only has format options and doesn't have any other options to make the SD card as an internal/default storage.

Comment: try to partition from adb shell https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213312

Comment: if you're planning to root your phone 1) get full ROM dump 2) unlock bootloader with [mtkclient](https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient) 3) patch boot with [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk) 4) disable [vbmeta](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219968) from fastboot 5) try to [port](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/3843473) from other device [TWRP](https://unofficialtwrp.com/twrp-3-5-0-root-ulefone-armor-x7-pro) (optional) 6) disable [encryption](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/3817389) (optional, edit [super.img](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221947)) 7) install Link2SD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update to Magisk 24.1. Support for XPosed modules / Changes](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/245242/update-to-magisk-24-1-support-for-xposed-modules-changes)