# How to root Redmi Note 11?

Tags: root-access, xiaomi, android-12, redmi-note-11

I want to root my device Redmi Note 11. I tried looking up online but could not find any thorough and updated guide. I don't want to brick my phone by following them.
Please, can anyone **guide me through the process of rooting** my device?

If it is possible, steps to pass the **SafetyNet** too.

Device specs:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: kindly read the \* manual https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk

Comment: You are right! rooting is a bit complex process; without any technical knowledge or being a novice user, one should follow the step-by-step guide to get a successful ending. Reading the below comprehensive guide on rooting Xiaomi redmi note 11 might help you in this regard. [How To Root Xiaomi Redmi Note 11? step-by-step guide](https://xiaomifix.com/root-xiaomi-redmi-note-11/)

Comment: @MilesMorales glad you solved your question. kindly write up self-answer to your question and mark as solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update to Magisk 24.1. Support for XPosed modules / Changes](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/245242/update-to-magisk-24-1-support-for-xposed-modules-changes)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I managed to root my device successfully.

Comment: I asked the same question on XDA forums. And after unlocking the bootloader I followed this thread. https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-root-redmi-note-11.4539979/