# How to install Xposed framework on Android 12? What about safety net?

Tags: magisk, google-pixel-4a, safety-net, android-12, lsposed

Further to these questions:

- [What are the alternatives for Xposed framework on Pie? Preferably without triggering Safety Net?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207633/131553)
- [How to install EdXposed on Android 10 without triggering safety net](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218179/how-to-install-edxposed-on-android-10-without-triggering-safety-net)
- [How to install EdXposed on Android 11? What about safety net?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231176/131553)

**How does one install Xposed framework on Android 12?**

**Notes:**

1. This is a self answered question for the *fourth year* on this subject!  Edxposed is still in beta and Android 12 is recently released, so there would be many changes to this answer in future. Since I do not intend to update this answer with developments, others are welcome to add and modify - sadly, in the previous three questions, there hasn't been a single edit barring mine :( , so this may help the diminishing breed of Xposed module enthusiasts.
2. Answer is generic in nature and for issues relating to installation / modules you are better off asking in respective device/module threads in XDA.

Moderators are welcome to make this a community wiki if warranted.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is valid on the day of posting and it is *very unlikely* I would be updating it. Please feel free to edit this or add a separate answer

---

Firstly,[edxposed](/questions/tagged/edxposed) was the way in recent years.However,developers never provided adequate documentation and the Telegram channels are mostly in Chinese making it difficult to understand. Anecdotally, there have been differences in the team members (core Riru module and Yahfa/Sandhook drivers are developed separately), vouched for by developers on XDA. To make things worse,differences have reached a stage wherein the latest Riru module is incompatible with drivers and users are advised *not* to update. Driver developers termed this [*irresponsible change of Riru*](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed/issues/878).

Secondly, the drivers have also not been updated to support Android 12.

**Lsposed**

Given these, the alternative was [lsposed](/questions/tagged/lsposed), which again anecdotally is developed by break-away members of the Edxposed team. There is an [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/lsposed-xposed-framework-8-0-12-0-simple-magisk-module-edxposed-alternative.4228973/)  maintained by a user.

I had tried Lsposed earlier but didn't like it

- because of their design wherein you need to deliberately select each and every app that you want an xposed module to hook into.Same logic applies for system components. Repeat this for every app/module you install(there is an [automation workaround](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/lsposed-xposed-framework-8-0-12-0-simple-magisk-module-edxposed-alternative.4228973/post-85827845) though)
- Another difficulty is that unless the module developer specifies what system components are to enabled, it is a guessing game with unpredictable results.The developers however, consider this their core philosophy. Conversely, because of this , system lag is reduced.

**Installation**

- After rooting device with magisk, install latest/compatible Riru Core module from [github](https://github.com/RikkaApps/Riru/releases) or magisk repo (v26.1.3, in this case).
- Install the latest.compatible lsposed module from [github](https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPosed/releases) (v1.6.2, in this case).
- Once you install lsposed , it creates a shortcut on your launcher to manage  module installation. It has a module repo too (beta). This manager is called *parasitic manager*, since the app is hidden in the app drawer to prevent detection but you get a regular app shortcut on your home screen. If you choose to install from the built-in repo, you are saved the bother of figuring out what system components need to be hooked.

Setting it up was a breeze and the easiest xposed framework installation for me over last 7 years.

[XPrivacy Lua](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacylua6-0-android-privacy-manager-t3730663) works, so does [XPosed Edge Pro](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-edgepro-v2-0-release-t3525566). Though these modules haven't been updated yet for Android 12, they work to the extent I need.

**Safety Net**

As explained in [Magisk will fail Safety-Net hereafter. Why?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221976/131553), safety net bypass is increasingly tough or impossible with recent devices. I wasn't keen to have the safety net status green since I don't use apps that demand this. However, one banking app refused to work as it detected root,despite enabling it in magisk hide. Since I wanted to have that app running , this is how I could pass safety net. YMMV may vary.

- Installed this Magisk module [[XPosed]DevOptsHide (Hide developer options)[ROOT]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.accelf.devoptshide) which claims to hide root and also hide developer option status. It didn't help me with this banking app.
- [Universal SafetyNet Fix](https://github.com/kdrag0n/safetynet-fix) Magisk module did the trick and I was able to pass safety net check and get the banking app running. It is interesting to learn how it works (for details see the linked page)

  - It prevents hardware based  safety net detection and forces basic attestation which is easier to fool.
  - Google knows which devices support hardware detection so it presents device as  a *different device* by *appending a space character to the device model name*

With magisk set to drop [magisk hide feature with future upgrades](https://mobile.twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1445598597521633285), fooling safety net detection is going to be tougher if not impossible.