# Revert volume button behavior

Tags: volume

I recently "upgraded" against my will from Oreo to Pie, and two problems that weren't there came up:

- The volume button used to change the notification volume. Now it changes the Media
- The icon right below the level indicator used to expand two other columns of levels, enabling me to control the media and ringtone level. Now it opens the settings instead.

Is there a way to revert these stupid changes ?

I imagine XPosed must have a module for that...

Comment: 1. First point- it's an Android version  planned change 2. Gravity Box module can do what you want 3. [Follow this to install Lsposed](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242274/131553) 4. [Depending on your magisk version, you may need to install Zygisk version](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245242/131553) 5. Links were valid at the time of writing the answer, you would need to install later updated versions

Comment: Thank you. Will try those. I write xposed for habit. It's LSPosed I have. In fact, I had to migrate from Oreo only to  be able to use LSPosed

Comment: Hey, @beeshyams, GravityBox exceeded the expectations ! Make it an answer and I'll mark it as solution

Comment: Thank you but I don't have gravity box being on Android 12 and it would make a poor answer without details. Kindly self answer with details, so that it helps others too and yes ping me for an up vote

Answer (score 0):

One XPosed module, **GravityBox**, fixed both my problem (credits to beeshyams).

After installing it (if you are lucky), do mark under **Media Tweaks**, ***Force ring volume control*** and ***Expanded volume panel***

Tested only on GravityBox [P], but probably valid for any version